# Bad request encountered with RestSharp JSON POST request

Tags: c#, json, post, restsharp, web-api-testing

I am using RestSharp to make a POST request containing a JSON body.  But I get a Bad request error.

Because I have `[]` and `""` in my JSON I have decided to use Newtonsoft.Json   . Before using this I couldn't even see a JSON request being formed.

I am willing to try `MS httpwebrequest` as an alternative.

```
restClient = new RestClient();

restRequest = new RestRequest(ApiUrl, Method.POST, DataFormat.Json);

var myObject = "{ \"target\" : \"[5,5]\", \"lastseen\" : \"1555459984\" }";

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject);
restRequest.AddParameter("application/json", ParameterType.RequestBody);

restRequest.AddJsonBody(json);
```

**Please note that I am trying to convert a JSON curl to C#.  Please see below:**

`curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST -d '{ "target" : [5, 5],  "lastseen" : "1555459984", "previousTargets" : [ [1, 0], [2, 2], [2, 3] ] }' http://santized/santized/santized`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You appear to be over serializing the data to be sent.

Consider creating an object and then passing it to `AddJsonBody`.

```
//...

restClient = new RestClient();

restRequest = new RestRequest(ApiUrl, Method.POST, DataFormat.Json);

var myObject = new { 
    target = new []{ 5, 5 }, 
    lastseen = "1555459984",
    previousTargets = new []{
        new [] { 1, 0 }, 
        new [] { 2, 2 }, 
        new [] { 2, 3 } 
    }
};

restRequest.AddJsonBody(myObject); //this will serialize the object and set header

//...
```

`AddJsonBody` sets content type to `application/json` and serializes the object to a JSON string.

Comment: I am trying to convert a JSON curl to C#. Perhaps that might be the issue?  I have updated my post above.

Comment: All the parameters are string

Comment: @CodeRocker not according to the curl you posted. target is a number array

Comment: Oh I see - you are right about that!  It is a number array.  The curl works.

Comment: @CodeRocker check my updated answer that should match the curl

Comment: Hey, @Nkosi thanks so much for your help, it now works! :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just this?

```
restClient = new RestClient();

restRequest = new RestRequest(ApiUrl, Method.POST, DataFormat.Json);

var myObject = "{ \"target\" : \"[5,5]\", \"lastseen\" : \"1555459984\" }";

restRequest.AddParameter("application/json", ParameterType.RequestBody);

restRequest.AddJsonBody(json);
```

Removed the line where you are serializing a json string.

Comment: Yep removed the line as suggested.  But that didn't work either.

Comment: @CodeRocker you need to clarify what the API expects. If it is returning a BadRequest then it means the data is not being sent correctly, but we can't help you if we don't know what the API is expecting.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string target { get; set; }
    public string lastseen { get; set; }
}

restClient = new RestClient();

restRequest = new RestRequest(ApiUrl, Method.POST, DataFormat.Json);

RootObject myObject = new RootObject();
myObject.target = "[5,5]";
myObject.lastseen = "1555459984";
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject);

restRequest.AddParameter("application/json", ParameterType.RequestBody);

restRequest.AddJsonBody(json);
```

Comment: `"previousTargets" : [ [1, 0], [2, 2], [2, 3] ] }' ` how would you represent this as an array?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you could do this example:

```
  public static IRestRequest PostInformationAndPassToken(JsonObject tokenString, string path, string whatistobePosted)
    {
        IRestRequest request = new RestRequest(path, Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", $"Bearer {tokenString["Token"]}");
        request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request.AddParameter(whatistobePosted, ParameterType.RequestBody); 
        return request;
    }
```